# Why does \renewcommand{\Pr} trigger "Limit controls must follow a math operator" with MathJax+htlatex?

Tags: errors, htlatex

I have `ht5mjlatex.cfg` as defined [**here**](/a/68962/2694), and a `foo.tex` containing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\Pr}[1]{P(#1)}
\begin{document}
    $\Pr{h}$
\end{document}
```

As described in that post, I try to convert it to MathJax-HTML. When I try

```
htlatex foo.tex ht5mjlatex.cfg
```

I receive the following error:

```
! Limit controls must follow a math operator.
\n:limits: ->\o:limits:
                        \:l:mits
l.4     $\Pr
         {h}$
?
! Emergency stop.
```

**Why** does this problem occur? I can work around it by avoiding redefining `\Pr` and such, but for the life of me I can't understand what it should be occurring in the first place.

Comment: Is defining `\Pr` as `\mathop{P(#1)}` any help? I can only guess that htlatex tries to add a `\limits` or `\nolimits` command after `\Pr` which doesn't work in your redefined command.

Comment: @siracusa: Nope I in fact had `\mathop` originally. It's the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delay the `\renewcommand`, or it would be overridden by the default definitions.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\Pr}[1]{P(#1)}%
}

\begin{document}
    $\Pr{h}$
\end{document}
```

The dangers of using `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation on why it fails with `htlatex`? In a normal document it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @siracusa `\Pr` is a core command of LaTeX and the specific files of TeX4ht have to “translate” it into something manageable by HTML; they do the job at begin document, so the redefinition of `\Pr` gets overridden. Why the error is about `\limits` I don't really know.

Comment: @egreg: *"they do the job at begin document, so the redefinition of \Pr gets overridden"*... Confused, so why is there no error if I remove the `\renewcommand`?

Comment: @Mehrdad The original `\Pr` is a `\mathop`, so inserting one of the limits commands after it is correct

Comment: @siracusa: But `\renewcommand{\Pr}[1]{\mathop{P(#1)}}` doesn't work...?

Answer (score 1):

As this is too long for the comments: Based on egreg's answer, I *think* what happens is that htlatex adds a hook to the preamble that looks something like

```
\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldPr=\Pr \renewcommand\Pr{\oldPr\nolimits}}
```

with additional code for generating the HTML output.

The standard definition for`\Pr` is

```
\newcommand\Pr{\mathop{\operator@font Pr}}
```

so an example usage of `\Pr{h}` then would expand as

```
\Pr{h}
\oldPr\nolimits{h}
\mathop{\operator@font Pr}\nolimits{h}
```

which gives a correct usage of `\nolimits` as it occurs after a `\mathop`.

Now add your redefinition to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\Pr}[1]{\mathop{P(#1)}}
```

The expansion of `\Pr{h}` now looks like

```
\Pr{h}
\oldPr\nolimits{h}
\mathop{P(\nolimits)}{h}
```

As you can see, the `\nolimits` is now parsed as first argument of your new `\Pr` definition thereby going at a wrong position, especially not after a `\mathop`, which gives the error message you receive

```
! Limit controls must follow a math operator.
```